# batch script that grants admin rights and goes through all files and folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, icacls

I have this, pretty sure its a little harsh but does the job, gives me all the rights to the files and folders on a drive when run on a drive, now I need help getting it to go into sub directories, so I dont need to copy the bat script inside every folder and have to run it.

```
takeown /f *
icacls * /grant Administrator:F
icacls * /grant Administrators:F
icacls * /grant SYSTEM:F
icacls * /grant "Authenticated Users":F
```

How would I get it to traverse the drive recursively?

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer:** [add `/t` to (i)cacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

**Long answer:**

Here is my script I use when I want the file to be accessible to any user. It includes comments on what each flag does. Just put this in a batch file somewhere in the `%AppData%` folder.

```
REM --v2 -----------------------------------------------------------
takeown /r /d y /f %1
icacls %1 /t /grant Everyone:F

REM takeown /r /d y /f will set the owner to the Administrators group recursively.
REM /t makes it recursive
REM /grant Sets the permision to the following user, replaces existing permissions for the specified uesr.
REM :f Grants full controll permission.
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------

REM --v1 -----------------------------------------------------------
REM cacls %1 /t /e /g Everyone:f

REM /t makes it recursive
REM /e Edits the ACL instead of replaceing it
REM /g Grants permissions to the following users
REM :f Grants full controll permission.
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` create a shortcut to the batch script.

Edit the properties of that shortcut and go to `Advanced...` and check the box `Run as Administrator.`

[image]

Now in your `right click menu -> Send To` you will have a item called `Fix Permissions` any file or folder you do a `Send To` on will have the Everyone group given `Full Access` permissions. If you perform it on a folder it will recursively go through it and apply the permissions to all of the children in the folder.

---

I save the batch file the `%AppData%` folder because I am on a domain and that makes it part of my roaming profile so it will be on and ready to use on any computer I connect to.

Comment: you might want to add `takeown` as well. https://gist.github.com/972013

Comment: @Sathya very cool, never knew about that, I am adding it to my script

Comment: Looks good Scott!

Comment: how do you remove the current folder/files security settings, before adding new ones?

Comment: @wiak by using `/grant:r` instead of `/grant`. I wanted to keep the existing ones and add `Full Control` to the `Everyone` group.

Comment: I'm following this exact method but [it's not working as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893844/send-to-a-folder-over-to-a-batch-script-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: found this, it works much better http://teejee2008.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/fixing-ntfs-file-permissions/

Comment: @wiak To me, it is so easy to just write up a script I rather do that than trust a program I know nothing about. That way I know exactly what is happening to my computer (especially a program which I will be running as an administrator)

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for network shares?

```
Takeown /f *
icacls * /grant Administrator:F
icacls * /grant Administrators:F
icacls * /grant SYSTEM:F
icacls * /grant "Authenticated Users":F
icacls * /grant "doamin\users":R
```